# Where can I see my latest history in my GitHub feed?

Tags: github

Using GitHub since many years back and it has been changed drastically. It looks good but I am struggling to find recent activity on my feed, I have to go through long route:

Click on top repository and see commit details.

or

Activity overview comes very down.

Is there any settings which show my recent activity on top of my feed, currently how it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: On your profile there is a tab "Contribution Activity" that shows your recent activity.

Comment: I cant find such tab..